# SABR Question: Why does the market take the beta parameter as a constant?

Tags: stochastic-volatility, sabr

**SABR Question**

Why does the market take the $\beta$ parameter as a "constant"?

- I see most brokers quoting SABR parameters nowadays.
- I've seen many banks use $\beta$=0.5 as a rule.
- I've seen quants select a $\beta$ based on best fit to calibration instruments.

What is most correct to the spirit of the paper, and explain any issues to anticipate with IMR/IPV processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Managing Smile risk](http://web.math.ku.dk/%7Erolf/SABR.pdf) from Hagan et. al.

Generally if you pre-select $\beta$, it is from a priori considerations.

- $\beta = 1$ corresponds to stochastic lognormal
- $\beta = 0$ is stochastic normal
- $\beta=1/2$ CIR

In the SABR model, beta is usually calibrated first, followed by the other 3 parameters. Frequently, instead of calibrating beta, it is simply assumed to have $\beta=1/2$ (since CIR is widely used). That said, JPY it is also natural to select 0 for JPY due to negative rates.
The paper explains both. "Aesthetic" consideration (a priori - fixed) or determined form historical observations.

Click [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/63750/54838) for an intuitive explanation of the SABR model. How to estimate $\beta$ can be seen in [this answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/74208/54838).