# Closed form solution to get implied vol from delta with SABR model

Tags: implied-volatility, sabr

Given a set of calibrated SABR parameters, what is the approach to get the implied vol for a given delta ?
thanks

Comment: I'd say solve delta for the forward and plug the forward into the equations shown on P.91 of the article Managing Smile risk from Hagan et. al in the Willmott magazine as shown [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/75169/54838).