QuantLib Swaption Pricing
I'm trying to replicate Bloomberg's swaption pricer(SWPM -OV) in QauntLib. I'm using the same curve(USD SOFR) for both forward and discount curves. However, the code I wrote in python gave me unreasonable npv - in this example, npv= 8.97 and delta= 235944.37 for a 1MM notional 1Mx10Y swaption, while I was expecting NPV=10359 and delta=-414 as shown Bloomberg (see picture attached).
I have searched relevant posts but couldn't solve the problem. Something must be totally off given the scale of the outputs is completely wrong.
Below is my code, which should be able to run given the right file path. Sorry for the code complexity, you can ignore the helper functions. I'm attaching the complete code in case anyone needs to run it himself.
import pandas as pd
import os
import datetime
import QuantLib as ql
import numpy as np

def get_swap(forward_term_structure, fixed_coupon_rate, notional, start_data, maturity_date, fixed_payment_frequency, 
                float_payment_frequency, pay_rec=ql.Swap.Payer):
    calendar = ql.UnitedStates(ql.UnitedStates.FederalReserve)

    if not isinstance(start_data, ql.Date):
        start_data = datetime_to_ql_date(start_data)
    if not isinstance(maturity_date, ql.Date):
        maturity_date = datetime_to_ql_date(maturity_date)

    index = ql.USDLibor(ql.Period('1Y'), forward_term_structure)

    fixed_leg_tenor = ql.Period(*parse_frequency(fixed_payment_frequency)) # payment frequency
    fixed_leg_adjustment = ql.ModifiedFollowing
    fixed_leg_daycount = ql.Actual360() # convention

    floating_leg_tenor = ql.Period(*parse_frequency(float_payment_frequency))
    floating_leg_adjustment = ql.ModifiedFollowing
    floating_leg_daycount = ql.Actual360()

    fixed_schedule = ql.Schedule(
        start_data,
        maturity_date,
        fixed_leg_tenor,
        calendar, 
        fixed_leg_adjustment,
        fixed_leg_adjustment,
        ql.DateGeneration.Forward,
        False
    )

    floating_schedule = ql.Schedule(
        start_data,
        maturity_date,
        floating_leg_tenor,
        calendar,
        floating_leg_adjustment,
        floating_leg_adjustment,
        ql.DateGeneration.Forward,
        False
    )

    swap = ql.VanillaSwap(
        pay_rec,
        notional,
        fixed_schedule,
        fixed_coupon_rate,
        fixed_leg_daycount,
        floating_schedule,
        index,
        0.0,
        floating_leg_daycount
    )

    return swap


def swaption_pricer(swap_rates, volatility, evaluation_date, exercise_date, settlement_date, maturity_date, notional, fixed_coupon_rate,   
                    fixed_payment_frequency, float_payment_frequency, pay_rec=ql.Swap.Payer, mode='forward'):

    calendar = ql.UnitedStates(ql.UnitedStates.FederalReserve)
    
    if not isinstance(evaluation_date, ql.Date):
        evaluation_date = datetime_to_ql_date(evaluation_date)
    if not isinstance(exercise_date, ql.Date):
        exercise_date = datetime_to_ql_date(exercise_date)
    if not isinstance(settlement_date, ql.Date):
        settlement_date = datetime_to_ql_date(settlement_date)
    if not isinstance(maturity_date, ql.Date):
        maturity_date = datetime_to_ql_date(maturity_date)

    ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = evaluation_date

    dates, rates = zip(*swap_rates)
    dates, rates = list(dates), list(rates)

    curve_handle = None

    quotes = []
    swap_helpers = []
    for tenor, rate in swap_rates:
        quote = ql.SimpleQuote(rate)
        quotes.append(quote)
        swap_helpers.append(ql.SwapRateHelper(ql.QuoteHandle(quote),
                                            tenor_to_ql_period(tenor),
                                            calendar,
                                            ql.Annual,
                                            ql.ModifiedFollowing,
                                            ql.Actual360(),
                                            ql.USDLibor(ql.Period('1Y')))) #check the use of libor curve here
        
    forward_curve = ql.PiecewiseLinearForward(evaluation_date, swap_helpers, ql.Actual360())
    forward_curve.enableExtrapolation()
    curve_handle = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(forward_curve)

    black_engine = ql.BlackSwaptionEngine(curve_handle, ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(volatility)), ql.ActualActual(ql.ActualActual.ISMA))

    swap = get_swap(curve_handle, fixed_coupon_rate, notional, settlement_date, maturity_date, fixed_payment_frequency, float_payment_frequency, pay_rec)

    swaption = ql.Swaption(swap, ql.EuropeanExercise(exercise_date), ql.Settlement.Cash, ql.Settlement.ParYieldCurve)
    swaption.setPricingEngine(black_engine)

    try:
        npv = swaption.NPV()
    except:
        npv = np.nan
    try:
        delta = swaption.delta()
    except:
        delta = np.nan
    try:
        gamma = swaption.gamma()
    except:
        gamma = np.nan
    # vega and theta are not calculated
    vega = np.nan
    theta = np.nan

    return npv, delta, gamma, vega, theta

def datetime_to_ql_date(dt):
    """
    Converts a datetime object to a QuantLib Date object.
    
    Parameters:
    dt (datetime.datetime): The datetime object to convert.
    
    Returns:
    ql.Date: The corresponding QuantLib Date object.
    """
    day = dt.day
    month = dt.month
    year = dt.year
    
    # Map the month number to the corresponding QuantLib month enumeration
    ql_month = {
        1: ql.January, 2: ql.February, 3: ql.March, 4: ql.April,
        5: ql.May, 6: ql.June, 7: ql.July, 8: ql.August,
        9: ql.September, 10: ql.October, 11: ql.November, 12: ql.December
    }[month]
    
    return ql.Date(day, ql_month, year)

def tenor_to_ql_period(tenor):

    unit = tenor[-1]
    value = int(tenor[:-1])
    
    if unit == 'd':
        return ql.Period(value, ql.Days)
    elif unit == 'w':
        return ql.Period(value, ql.Weeks)
    elif unit == 'm':
        return ql.Period(value, ql.Months)
    elif unit == 'y':
        return ql.Period(value, ql.Years)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid tenor unit. Must be one of 'd', 'w', 'm', 'y'.")

def parse_frequency(frequency):
    frequency = frequency.lower()

    # Extract the numeric part and the unit
    number = int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, frequency)))
    unit = ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, frequency))

    # Map the unit to QuantLib period type
    if unit == 'y':
        return number, ql.Years
    elif unit == 'm':
        return number, ql.Months
    elif unit == 'd':
        return number, ql.Days
    elif unit == 'w':
        return number, ql.Weeks
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid period string format")
    

# Run from here
SRC_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)).replace('\\', '/')
PROJ_PATH = os.path.dirname(SRC_PATH).replace('\\', '/')
file_path = PROJ_PATH + '/test/rates.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(file_path)

def convert_tenor(tenor):
    return (tenor.replace(' MO', 'm')
                 .replace(' WK', 'w')
                 .replace(' YR', 'y'))

df['tenor'] = df['tenor'].apply(convert_tenor)

rates = list(zip(df['tenor'], df['rate'] / 100.0))
volatility = 0.010267
notional = 1e6
strike_price = 0.033674
evaluation_date = datetime.date(2024, 8, 14)
exercise_date = datetime.date(2024, 9, 16)
settle_date = datetime.date(2024, 9, 18)
maturity_date = datetime.date(2034, 9, 18)

npv, delta, gamma, vega, theta = swaption_pricer(rates, volatility, evaluation_date, exercise_date, settle_date, maturity_date,
                                                notional, strike_price, '1Y', '1Y', ql.Swap.Payer, mode='forward')

print(f'npv: {npv}, delta: {delta}, gamma: {gamma}, vega: {vega}, theta: {theta}')

Output:
npv: 8.971815427502813, delta: 235944.37335515753, gamma: nan, vega: nan, theta: nan

These are the rates I'm using which is copied from Bloomberg:
tenor,rate
1 WK,5.3341
2 WK,5.33585
3 WK,5.33814
1 MO,5.34261
2 MO,5.20565
3 MO,5.11385
4 MO,5.02265
5 MO,4.903
6 MO,4.7885
7 MO,4.7085
8 MO,4.60968
9 MO,4.52458
10 MO,4.44082
11 MO,4.3638
12 MO,4.2871
18 MO,3.9293
2 YR,3.7348
3 YR,3.5127
4 YR,3.40905
5 YR,3.36448
6 YR,3.349
7 YR,3.3454
8 YR,3.351
9 YR,3.36048
10 YR,3.37219
12 YR,3.40177
15 YR,3.43655
20 YR,3.4382
25 YR,3.3726
30 YR,3.2943
40 YR,3.1005
50 YR,2.90915




Note that BBG here uses the Normal (Bachelier) model, i.e., the 102bps of vol are in absolute units, whereas you use a Black Engine with relative units. 102bps with 10y rates around 350-400bps gives you a Black Scholes vol in the ballpark of 25-30%.

@KevinT Thanks for your comment. I changed vol to relative % which does give the right scale. But this is strange - why would balckengine take relative percentage instead of absolute value? The former will need a fair rate first, which will duplicate the code since you will need to build the curve twice. Also how would I know that blackengine takes relative value? Checked blackswaptionengine.hpp, but didn't find relevant documentation.

It's crucial to understand swaptions and market  quotes before trying to replicate. https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/74179/54838 has a quick overview and show how to black and normal model relate to each other.

@AKdemy Thanks for your comment. I read through your answer in that link and now understand that I was using the wrong model. Changed to Bachelier and things make sense now.

I'm answering this myself since the comments have pointed out the problem: the issue was because I was using the wrong model. Bloomberg convention is Normal model, while Black model assumes log normal. Changing BlackSwaptionEngine to BachelierSwaptionEngine gives the right number:
#black_engine = ql.BlackSwaptionEngine(curve_handle, ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(volatility)), ql.ActualActual(ql.ActualActual.ISMA))
bachelier_engine = ql.BachelierSwaptionEngine(curve_handle, ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(volatility)), ql.ActualActual(ql.ActualActual.ISMA))

